# Bipartite Graph or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

i have to determine whether this graph is bipartite or not:

[image]

I have found an answer but i am not sure about it. If we divide the vertices set into $\{a,d,c,h\}$ and $\{b,f,e,g\}$, then it fulfills bipartite properties.
Is it correct ?

Comment: You should at least explain what you think the "bipartite properties" are, and why you think that this graph satisfies them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test large graphs, use software, such as *Mathematica*:

```
myGraph = 
 Graph[{a \[UndirectedEdge] b, a \[UndirectedEdge] e, 
   a \[UndirectedEdge] f, b \[UndirectedEdge] h, 
   c \[UndirectedEdge] f, c \[UndirectedEdge] g, 
   d \[UndirectedEdge] e, d \[UndirectedEdge] f, 
   d \[UndirectedEdge] g, f \[UndirectedEdge] h}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
BipartiteGraphQ[myGraph]
```

(* True *)

Comment: thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe a $+1$ is in order, then.

Answer (score 1):

"The given graph is bipartite by the fact that there are no odd cycles in it". If you just want to prove it theoretically, this statement should be enough.

If you want to find out how it is bipartite then your sets of {a,d,c,h} and {b,f,e,g} are correct as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a graph is bipartite iff all its cycles have even length. Thus your graph is bipartite. To check that all cycles of your graph are actually of even length, we may apply the following result that can be proved by induction. Given a graph $G$ built up from even cycles connected by one edge, all cycles of $G$ are even.